# custom user login/register menu tabs

Tags: 7, users

I'm making a website with 2 different kind of users. using the [Profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) module, and i'm kind of stuck.

1. Tourists who register with the normal `user/register form`.
2. And Guides who register with a custom `guide/register form`.

On the homepage we have a simple user menu with login and register button.

I want to customize the tabs on the user/register page to have two tabs:
`Register as tourist` and `Register as guide`

So I want the tabs of `login` and `request password` to be gone on the registration forms.

**BUT** I do want the `login` and `request password` tabs on the login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add tpl file for user registration 
Example:

```
function THEME_NAME_theme() {  // Add this function in template.php
    $items = array();
    // create custom user-register.tpl.php
    $items['user_register'] = array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'THEME_NAME') . '/templates',
        'template' => 'user-register',
        'preprocess functions' => array(
        'THEME_NAME_preprocess_user_register'
        ),
    );
return $items;
}
```

According to role. add changes in user-register.tpl.php. You can refer link [to add user-register.tpl.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/1211520).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're wanting the use case covered by the [Profile2 Registration Path module](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath):

> By default, the Profile 2 module permits you to add fields from chosen
>   profile types to the default user registration form. Unfortunately,
>   there is only one user registration form. Thus, every user will be
>   presented with these fields during registration. If you have two
>   profile types targeted at two different audiences, you cannot have two
>   separate registration forms.

Anything else, might need to be covered by a form/menu altering custom module or [Tab Tamer](https://www.drupal.org/project/tabtamer).